# How to get more than one contacts in editTexts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have 3 editTexts and I want that the three editTexts should be filled with 3 diffrent contacts .Please Provide me help.I have googled it lot but not found any thing.All the links provided here works only for a single method.I set onclick listener for every edit Text but there is only one onActivityResult associated with the class which allows to set text only to one editText only.

Comment: startActivityForResult AND onActivityResult have [int requestCode] in paramters. Use requestCode to determine which editText is handling and fill text for it.

Comment: Okk...But I am new to this can you please share me any link if you know or code for two editTexts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startActivityForResult AND onActivityResult have [int requestCode] in paramters. 
 Use requestCode to determine which editText is handling and fill text for it

Call another activity:

```
startActivityForResult(newActivity, requestCode);
```

When result is returned:

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (requestCode) {
            case 1://working with first edit text
                //fill text for first edit text
                break;
            case 2://working with second edit text
                //fill text for second edit text
                break;
            case 3://working with third edit text
                //fill text for third edit text
                break;
            }
        }
```